# locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler is not receiving completion

Tags: swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I'm trying to integrate MapKit in my IOS app ,

I'm using LocationManager .

this is my code :

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.denied || status != CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted {
        getLocation()
    }
}

func getLocation(){
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler { (latitude, longitude, status, verboseMessage, error) -> () in
        self.displayLocation(location: CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))

    }



}

func displayLocation(location:CLLocation) {

    map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)), animated: true)

    //set pin
    let locationPinCOord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let annotaion = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotaion.coordinate = locationPinCOord

    map.addAnnotation(annotaion)
    map.showAnnotations([annotaion], animated: true)
    locationManager.reverseGeocodeLocationWithCoordinates(location) { (reverseGeocodeInfo, placemark, error) in
        print(reverseGeocodeInfo)
    }

}
```

but for some reason the displayLocation function is never called.

Comment: `getLocation()` is called?

Comment: yes , getLocation is called and then locationManager.startUpdatingLocationWithCompletionHandler is called but the function in the closure is never being called

Comment: Are you using a library for this? I don't find the method your trying to invoke in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager